# .done function is not working with defer and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

Things that I have tried: -

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
$("#Index").click(function(){
    dfd.resolve();  
}).done(function(){   
    CallNextFunction();  
})
```

I created a deferred object and when click is done, I want next function to be called but it never does.

Second Try

```
function CompletePage(){ 
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $("#Index").click(function(){
       dfd.resolve();                           
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}        

CompletePage().done(function(){
    // Call Next Function();
});
```

This also does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting the right element (``$("#Index")``)? The second version should work.

Comment: I'll replace my answer with a comment - Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ufLxyw80/

Comment: In your first version, you're calling `done` upon the jQuery collection, not the promise. Your second version should work fine. What exactly is the problem?